# how to display new text on a new page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a form in which, questions are displayed one by one when the user clicks the next button. I am able to display the first question, but don't know how to clear the dom and render the next question. i need to write a onclick function in javascript, that displays the next question and calculate the grade in the end.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function nextQuestion(){

        }
     </script>

    <form method="POST">
        <div id="page1">
            <div>question 1</div><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='group1' id='correct' value="1">1<br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='group1' id='2' value="2">2<br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='group1' id='3' value="3">3<br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='group1' id='4' value="4">4<br><br>
        </div>
    <button id="next" onclick="nextQuestion();">Next</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: How about hide and display your questions when the user clicks the next button ?

Comment: You Can have a look on IFramnes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nextQuestion(){
        var selectedVal = $(":radio[name=group1]:checked").text();
        $('#dv_question').empty().html('question ' + selectedVal);
    }
 </script>

<form method="POST">
    <div id="page1">
        <div id="dv_question">question 1</div><br><br>
        <input type='radio' name='group1' id='correct' value="1"<br><br>
        <input type='radio' name='group1' id='2' value="2">2<br><br>
        <input type='radio' name='group1' id='3' value="3">3<br><br>
        <input type='radio' name='group1' id='4' value="4">4<br><br>
    </div>
<button id="next" onclick="nextQuestion();">Next</button>
</form>
```

Hope this one help you.

Answer (score 0):

Load the QUESTION using AJAX Calling and replace
  content with the response from AJAX.